# Connection Managers don't work once I change the Protection Level

Tags: encryption, ssis, ssis-2008

Using SSIS 2008 currently, my package ProtectionLevel is set to: `EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey`.

I recently tried changing it to `DontSaveSensitive`
but my package fails after making that change with the following error:

```
 SSIS package "ImportModerators.dtsx" starting.
 Information: 0x4004300A at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.
 Error: 0xC020801C at Data Flow Task, Add new Moderators [422]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "StagingDatabase" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.
 Error: 0xC0047017 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: component "Add new Moderators" (422) failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.
 Error: 0xC004700C at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: One or more component failed validation.
 Error: 0xC0024107 at Data Flow Task: There were errors during task validation.
 SSIS package "ImportModerators.dtsx" finished: Success.
```

If I've changed the protection level (and I'm the one who created the package), shouldn't this package be able to run?

Comment: Is the Connection Manager, StagingDatabase, using Windows Authentication or does it take a username and password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the connection is not windows authentication, you will need to setup package configurations for each connection so SSIS has somewhere to pull credentials from.